# Not getting desired output for largest and smallest number in a given set of inputs

Tags: python

this is the program for finding out the largest ans smallest number in a given set of inputs. but somehow i am not getting the desired out put i e the largest and the smallest number.i checked it many times but i still cant understand the fault in the code. could you help me out please? For example if I give 7 and 2 as input 7 is given out as maximum and 2 as minimum but when I give 10 and 2 as input 2 is given out as maximum and 10 as minimum.

```
enter code here
largest = 0
smallest = None
#lis = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break 
    try:
        numb = float(num)
        #lis.append(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

#for value in lis:  
    if smallest == None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num


#for value in lis:
    if num > largest:
        largest = num 
    else:
        pass

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
enter code here
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem if you want help. "It's not giving the right answer when *I* run it" does not really qualify as a problem statement...

Comment: For example if I give 7 and 2 as input 7 is given out as maximum and 2 as minimum but when I give 10 and 2 as input 2 is given out as maximum and 10 as minimum.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61917438/edit) your question.

Comment: Did you comment out the important bits deliberately?

Comment: I was trying somethings.if i could go around by different approaches. And therefore I commented out somethings to try if it worked that way .it worked without the list also and the for loop was for iteration through the list. So I commented them .  I am pretty new to this. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

the error is that instead of num in the if statements you should use the numb like this:

```
largest = 0
smallest = None
#lis = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break 
    try:
        numb = float(num)
        #lis.append(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

#for value in lis:  
    if smallest == None:
        smallest = numb
    elif numb < smallest:
        smallest = numb


#for value in lis:
    if numb > largest:
        largest = numb 
    else:
        pass

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```